# charlierguo - gmail for python - Accessing other mailboxes and searching for attachments in gmail messages

Tags: python, email, gmail

I have recently installed the library by charlierguo - gmail for python. However looking at the github page I cannot figure out how to access any other mailbox other than the inbox.

I would like to access the ALL MAIL mailbox, and then search for emails from the ALL MAIL mailbox which contain attachments.

[The Gmail library for python](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail)

Comment: You want `label()` I believe. Gmail has a funny way to use labels instead of traditional folders.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, label() seems to work for Trash, but I can't get it to work for all mail. I have tried 'All Mail', 'all mail', 'all', 'allmail' etc.

Comment: plus the mailbox Trash for example has no get_item class so I'm not even sure how to extract the emails from the object.

Comment: With this design, your inbox contains "all mail" and folders are implemented as labels. There can be multiple labels or none at all, in which case a message is simply in the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should have looked at their code. They have defined many functions to access all folders of gmail like spam,sent,starred,important,inbox etc.

Accessing all mails in your inbox:

```
 from gmail import Gmail
 g = Gmail()
 g.login("username", "password")
 m = g.inbox().mail()
```

Similarly, to access sent mails, just change the function name:

```
from gmail import Gmail
g = Gmail()
g.login("username", "password")
m = g.sent_mail().mail()
```

You can have a look at all the functions you can use in his github code: [gmail github code](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail/blob/master/gmail/gmail.py)